# atoi doesnt seem to be working properly

Tags: c++, c, atoi

```
for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
{   
   char cst1[2] = {info[x+2], info[x+3]};
   char cst2[2] = {info[x+5], info[x+6]};
   sales[count][atoi(&info[x]) - 1] = atoi(cst1) + atoi(cst2);
   x += 8;
}
```

Every time i do the following code the atoi(cst1) value is multiplied by two then added and atoi(cst2) is multiplied by 100 then added cant figure out why

Comment: `cst1[2]` and cst2[2]` must be set to '\0'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cst1` and `cst2` don't appear to be NUL-terminated.

```
char cst1[] = {info[x+2], info[x+3], '\0'};
char cst2[] = {info[x+5], info[x+6], '\0'};
```